# Regular expressions using two separate patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a function that parses some text, and replaces any tags that are surrounded by `"{` and `}"` with values in an array.

```
function parse($template, array $values) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\{"{\ (\w+)\ \}\"/',function ($matches) use ($values) {
        return isset($values[$matches[1]])?$values[$matches[1]]:$matches[0];
        },
        $template);
}
```

How can it be modified to do the same, but also use a second deliminator? Specifically, I also which it to replace tags surrounded by `'{` and `}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option is to list possible delimiters explicitly:

```
$re = <<<RE
/
    "{ (\w+) }"
    |
    '{ (\w+) }'
/x
RE;
```

(using extended syntax for readability). The actual captured group will be at the end of the `matches` array:

```
preg_replace_callback($re, function ($matches) use ($values) {
        $word = end($matches);
        if (isset($values[$word])) etc....
},
```

This verbosity will pay off once you introduce more delimiters, especially non-symmetric ones, for example:

```
$re = <<<RE
/
    "{ (\w+) }"
    |
    '{ (\w+) }'
    |
    <{ (\w+) }>
    |
    {{ (\w+) }}
/x
RE;
```

Comment: Why `/x` and not just `/`?  Also, your use of `end` is just to get the last value in the array, right?  Will it not always be `$matches[1]`?

Comment: @user1032531: 1) `/x` = extended syntax. 2) No, it can be `matches[1]` or `matches[2]`, depending upon what has been matched.

Comment: Gotcha on the matches.  Never heard of extended syntax before.  Why in your example is it required/desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/\{['"]{\ (\w+)\ \}['"]/
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Will this not select `'{bla}"`?

Comment: @user1032531 That is why you need backreference

Comment: that's true, I assumed u did not care

Comment: if that is the case, I would say instead of using some complicated regexp, you would rather use two separate ones - much easier to maintain and for others to understand

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo remove slash `\[`, otherwise it escapes

Comment: Actually, I probably don't care, just curious.

Comment: @Cheery, right, thanks. Copied and forgot to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (did not check it) `/\{("|\'){\ (\w+)\ \}\1/` or `/\{(["\']){\ (\w+)\ \}\1/`

Comment: @user1032531 the first round captures either ' or " and at the end regexp uses backreference `\1` to that capture, so that the same symbol is used.

Comment: Ah, I somewhat understand.  The `1` is the back reference to it, right?  I didn't think you can include `or` in the patterns.  Opps, I just realized you provided two patterns :) One day I need to master regex!

Comment: @user1032531 not just `1`, it should be `\1`. Read http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php